# Using GPIO Pins of Raspberry Pi from scratch?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

How can I interact with the GPIO pins of a raspberry Pi without using an already implemented library?

I tried to go through the code of one of the implemented libraries (RPI.GPIO) but I didn't really go that far.

Do the GPIO pins show up as a device in the Pi? If so where can I locate them and interact with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15)
This is a great Tutorial for GPIO access from scratch. With the help of the datasheet this is a great point to start.

Comment: Beware that using such code (that directly manipulates the pinctrl registers) can interfere with the kernel's use of GPIOs, and can cause race conditions and device/system instability.  Trying to program a Linux system as if it was a microcontroller is misguided.